# Constant-gm bias circuit

Tags: mosfet, current-mirror, biasing, compensation, transconductance

I am doing a study on [Improvements in biasing and compensation of CMOS opamp](https://designers-guide.org/forum/Attachments/Improvements_in_biasing_and_compensation_of_CMOS_opamp.pdf#page=4).

Do you guys know how to come up with the equation for R<sub>DS4C</sub> ?

[image: a new gm-tracking lead compensation resistor]

Comment: I think it would be useful if you showed what you tried. Where are you stuck? Do you know where to begin?  Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance, that's for sure. And the circuit holds gm2E=gm4C. Now this conductance value must be for the conductance of the drain-source.

Comment: @DanielTork   gm2E=gm4C  ? Did you have a typing mistake or something else ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please explain.

Comment: What do you know about your question that could be useful for solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else had [derived the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3064.png)

[image]